# How to make a map in Neo4j's Neodash that pinpoints a city and makes a red circle around it given a specified radius

Tags: neo4j

I am working with neo4j's Neodash tool and I am creating a map. I want to pick a city on this map and draw a red circle around it given a radius. So, if I say a 25 mile radius around Los Angeles, I should see a red circle with a 25 mile radius on a map around LA. Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.